# I need to run a function when a jquery-ui tab is clicked, what have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I found the (modified) code below but the alert does not happen. Please help.
I also do not understand why the onclick is on "a[name=tab]", why not on "tab1" or a[tab1]?

```
  <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("a[name=tab]").click(function(e){
           if($(this).attr('id')=="tab1")
           {
              alert("1");
           }
           if($(this).attr('id')=="tab2")
           {
              alert("2");
           }
     });

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a name="tab" id="tab1" href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
           <li><a name="tab" id="tab2" href="#tabs-2">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>First tab.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Second tab.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I found there is a function that is run on tab change but I do not know how to use it and cannot find where to put it in my code. I would like help on this too. Thank you.

```
         $("#tabs").tabs({
                alert(ui.index);
             select: function(event, ui) {
                alert(ui.index);
                return true;
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [activate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) or [beforeActivate event](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            alert(ui.index);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, Why use `a[name=tab]` and not `[tab1]`?

`a[name=tab]` means an `a` tag with a `name` attribute equal to `tab`. 
If you use `a[tab1]` it means an `a` tag that has a `tab1` attribute.

You should check the jquery docs about it.
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

**Second**, your code isn't working because it has an error, but you can fix it like this:

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({
     select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.index);
        return true;
     }
 });
```

By the way, you should check about `jQuery UI` `tabs`
http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Google Cache of Tabs API documentation ;-): http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:FWoEECCxqHEJ:api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thank lots is avalible now.

Comment: Thank you Chokchai. The code for the second question does not work for me. I may not have it in the right place please let me know where in my code it is supposed to go.

Comment: Did you included jquery-ui ? if is yes. then try to put ` $("#tabs").tabs(...` function in `jQuery(document).ready(fuction($){...` scope.